# I have an error in android file

Tags: android, error-handling

addMember.java

```
EditText name,paid;
Button add;
final MyDBHandler db = new MyDBHandler(this);
String unpaid, inout="0";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_new_member);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
    paid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.PaidAmount);
    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addMember);


    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            unpaid=Integer.toString(250-(Integer.parseInt(paid.getText().toString())));

            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.add(new backService(name.getText().toString(),paid.getText().toString(),unpaid,inout));
            Intent intent=new Intent(addMember.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });




}
```

backService.java

```
private int _id;
private String message,number,con_name,date;

public backService(){}

public backService(String msg,String num,String con_na,String dat){
    this.message=msg;
    this.number=num;
    this.con_name=con_na;
    this.date=dat;
}


  //SETTERS
 public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public void setCon_name(String con_id) {
    this.con_name = con_id;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

//END SETTERS


 //GETTERS
public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getCon_name() {
    return con_name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

//END GETTERS
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
Activity context;
String name[];
String paid[];
String unpaid[];
int state[];

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String[] name, String[] paid, String[] unpaid, int[] state) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.name = name;
    this.paid = paid;
    this.unpaid=unpaid;
    this.state=state;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return name.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtViewName;
    TextView txtViewPaid;
    TextView txtViewUnpaid;
    Switch in_outSwitch;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_text, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.patricipants);
        holder.txtViewPaid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.money_paid);
        holder.txtViewUnpaid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.money_due);
        holder.in_outSwitch= (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inorout);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtViewName.setText(name[position]);
    holder.txtViewPaid.setText(paid[position]);
    holder.txtViewUnpaid.setText(unpaid[position]);
    if(state[position]==0){
        holder.in_outSwitch.setChecked(false);
    }
    else{
        holder.in_outSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
ListView lv;
CustomAdapter ca;
String[] name,paid,unpaid;
int[] state,ids;
MyDBHandler dbh;
int positions;
updater upd;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    name=dbh.ret_name();
    paid=dbh.ret_paidAmt();
    unpaid=dbh.ret_unpaidAmt();
    ids=dbh.ret_id();
    state=dbh.ret_inORout();


    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.nameSpace);
    ca=new CustomAdapter(this,name,paid,unpaid,state);

    lv.setAdapter(ca);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopup(view);
        }
    });


    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            showcontextmenu(view,position);
            return true;
        }
    });

}




public void showcontextmenu(View v,int position) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(this,v);
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.listviewpress,popupMenu.getMenu());
    positions=position;
    popupMenu.show();

}


public void showPopup(View v)
{
    PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(this,v);
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.show();

}







@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;

    //Handle ItemClicks HERE
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete:
            dbh.deleteuser(name[positions]);
            return true;
        case R.id.update:
            upd.name=name[positions];
            upd.paid=paid[positions];
            upd.id=Integer.toString(ids[positions]);
            intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,updater.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           return true;
        case R.id.addMember:
            intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,addMember.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.delAll:
            dbh.deldb();
            return true;



        default:
            return false;
    }
}














@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    onMenuItemClick(item);

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

MyDBHandler.java

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "picnic.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME="members";
private static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";
private static final String COLUMN_MSG="_name";
private static final String COLUMN_NUM="_paid";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME="_unpaid";
private static final String COLUMN_TIME="_inORout";

public long s;
public int size;

public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

 // FINDS THE SIZE OF A COLUMN IN A DATABASE
public void get_dbSize(){
    SQLiteDatabase db= getWritableDatabase();
    s= DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
            COLUMN_NUM + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_MSG + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT " +
            ");";

    db.execSQL(query);
    get_dbSize();
    size=(int)s;

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}


public void deldb(){
    SQLiteDatabase db =getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);


}


 // ADD A NEW DATA IN THE DATA BASE
public void add(backService BackService){
    ContentValues values =new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NUM, BackService.getNumber());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, BackService.getCon_name());
    values.put(COLUMN_MSG, BackService.getMessage());
    values.put(COLUMN_TIME,BackService.getDate());

    SQLiteDatabase db =getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();
}


public void deleteuser(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db =getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ COLUMN_MSG + "= \"" + name +"\";");
}




public void updateuser(String Value1, String Value2, String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME+" SET "+COLUMN_MSG+ " = \'"+Value1+"\' WHERE "+COLUMN_ID+" = \'"+id+"\' ;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME+" SET "+COLUMN_NUM+ " = \'"+Value2+"\' WHERE "+COLUMN_ID+" = \'"+id+"\' ;");

}


/*
//
//
//
 */


public String[] ret_paidAmt(){
    String[] phn_num=new String[size];
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_NUM+" FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";               `enter code here`
    int count=0;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null); //Cursor point to a location in results.
    cursor.moveToFirst(); //Move to the first row in results.
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NUM)) != null) {
            phn_num[count] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NUM));
            count++;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return phn_num;
}

// GET NAME FROM THE DB
public String[] ret_name(){
    String[] phn_msg=new String[size];
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_MSG+" FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";
             //Select every column, select every row.
    int count=0;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null); //Cursor point to a location in results.
    cursor.moveToFirst(); //Move to the first row in results.
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MSG)) != null) {
            phn_msg[count] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MSG));
            count++;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return phn_msg;

}

 // GET UNPAID AMOUNT FROM DB
public String[] ret_unpaidAmt(){
    String[] phn_conna=new String[size];
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
   String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_NAME+" FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";
    //Select every column, select every row.
    int count=0;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null); //Cursor point to a location in results.
    cursor.moveToFirst(); //Move to the first row in results.
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)) != null) {
            phn_conna[count] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
            count++;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return phn_conna;


}

  // GET ID OF CONTACT FROM DB
public int[] ret_id(){
    int[] con_id=new int[size];
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_ID+" FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1"; 
    //Select every column, select every row.
    int count=0;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null); 
     //Cursor point to a location in results.
    cursor.moveToFirst(); //Move to the first row in results.
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)) != null) {
            con_id[count] = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
            count++;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return con_id;


}

 // GET IN OR OUT FROM DB
public int[] ret_inORout(){
    int[] rec_time=new int[size];
    String temp;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_TIME+" FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";  
    //Select every column, select every row.
    int count=0;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null); //Cursor point to a location in results.
    cursor.moveToFirst(); //Move to the first row in results.
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TIME)) != null) {
             temp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TIME));
            rec_time[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp.trim());
            count++;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return rec_time;


}
```

updater.java

```
EditText nameField,paymentField;
Button updateButton;
TextView textView;
String name,paid,id;
MyDBHandler dbh;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.updatemember);

    nameField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameOfMember);
    paymentField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.amtPaidByUser);
    updateButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
    textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Remaining);

    nameField.setText(name);
    paymentField.setText(paid);
    updatetext();

    paymentField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!paymentField.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                updatetext();

            }

        }
    });

    updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name=nameField.getText().toString();
            paid=paymentField.getText().toString();
            dbh.updateuser(name,paid,id);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name+" is updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(updater.this,MainActivity.class);

        }
    });






}
public void updatetext(){
    textView.setText(Integer.toString((250-Integer.parseInt(paid))));
}
```

logCat

```
>FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.neil.picnicrecord, PID: 22647
                                                                               Theme: themes:{}
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.neil.picnicrecord/com.example.neil.picnicrecord.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] com.example.neil.picnicrecord.MyDBHandler.ret_name()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5471)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] com.example.neil.picnicrecord.MyDBHandler.ret_name()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.neil.picnicrecord.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7125)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5471) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) >
```

I an having an exception and i don't know where is it occurring and how to handle it if there are any more errors please tell me.

Comment: seem that that MyDBHandler dbh is null

Answer (score 1):

In your `MainActivity.java` you are calling

```
name=dbh.ret_name();
```

but `dbh` is not istantiated.

add this line bofore the one i posted above:

```
dbh = new MyDbHandler(this);
```

and you will fix it

Comment: still the same problem stays

Comment: no is done now i resynced the gradle files

Comment: @Neil glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You must instantiate your MyDBHandler.